# Mysql get a +-3 int value against a column value

Tags: mysql

The MySQL table is having a column 'weight' of type int, now when the select query runs I need to fetch a list of int values with +-3 for 'weight' column value.
I am stuck with this, tried a few approaches but didn't get the expected output.

Ex: I have the following dataset

```
mysql> select weight from health_records limit 3;
+----------+
| weight   |
+----------+
|   78     |
|   88     |
|   56     |
+----------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Want this output

```
mysql> select *something using weight* from health_records limit 3;
+--------------------------+
|       weight_range       |
+--------------------------+
|   75,76,77,78,79,80,81   |
|   85,86,87,88,89,90,91   |
|   53,54,55,56,57,58,59   |
+--------------------------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: What version of MySQL?

Comment: Is 3 a fixed value or can it change? And do you really want the result as CSV?

Comment: Use CONCAT_WS and static calculations for 5+, CTE and GROUP_CONCAT for 8+.

Comment: Handle issues of data display in application code

Comment: @Nick Mysql version is 8

Comment: @P.Salmon Yes that the requirement from Machine Learning side, maybe this value can change

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT CONCAT_WS(',', 
                 weight - 3,
                 weight - 2,
                 weight - 1,
                 weight,
                 weight + 1,
                 weight + 2,
                 weight + 3) weights
FROM health_records 
-- ORDER BY ??? - compulsory if LIMIT is used
LIMIT 3;
```